# Mean First Passage Time

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stochastic-processes

I am trying to read Robert Zwanzig's paper `Diffusion in a rough potential' and am getting bogged down in notation. He says the mfpt is found by solving the differential equation

$e^{\beta U(x)}\partial/\partial x De^{-\beta U(x)}\partial/\partial x\langle t,x\rangle =-1$

Because he has written it all on one line I can't work out which bits are doing what. Is it supposed to be

$e^{\beta U(x)} \frac{\partial D}{\partial x} e^{-\beta U(x)}\frac{\partial \langle t,x\rangle}{\partial x}=-1$

is it a product of terms?

Based on Ian's helpful comment it may be

$e^{\beta U(x)} \frac{\partial \left(De^{-\beta U(x)}\frac{\partial \langle t,x\rangle}{\partial x}\right) }{\partial x} =-1$

Comment: I'd have to examine the context but this looks generally along the lines of a divergence form differential operator, in which case you can understand the differential operators to be acting on everything on their right, e.g. the first $\partial_x$ acts on the whole expression $D e^{-\beta U} \partial_x \langle t,x \rangle$.

Comment: That sounds possible. I'm reading Zeev Schuss' book `Theory and Applications of Stochastic Processes' and he seems to be using something like that.